# Python: importing module from subdirectory that loads non-python file with relative path

Tags: python, import, path

This is my first python project for which I am trying to build professional structure/hierarchy. I have the following directory structure:

```
project/  
---__init__.py  
---main.py  
---data_lib/  
------__init__.py  
------load.py  
------file.csv
```

The code in load.py is:

```
import pandas as pd
def load_csv():
    print pd.read_csv('file.csv')
if __name__=='__main__':
    load_csv()
```

The code in main.py is:

```
from data_lib.load import load_csv
load_csv()
```

When load.py is run on its own I get a printout of a pandas dataframe of the loaded csv file. When main.py is run I get the error IOError: File file.csv does not exist. I can solve this by adding a path prefix before 'file.csv' defined by:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    path_prefix=''
else:
    path_prefix='data_lib/'
```

Is this the standard solution and programming practice or should I be avoiding this and doing something else instead (especially since the csv file will be one that will need to be regularly updated without any other code files impacted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common idiom in situations like this is to prefix all your file paths with the absolute path to your module:

```
from os import path

path_prefix = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
csv_path = path.join(path_prefix, 'file.csv')
```

This way it doesn't matter where you are calling the module from, you will still be able to load resources from within the module.

Adding a path prefix as you have described will only work when you are calling the module from the parent directory. What happens when you call it from somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, and an easy change. I knew there would be problem with naming my file, file.csv for this example. Readers should note \__file__ is a built in name and not related to name of my file!

Comment: Yep, `__file__` is a built-in which gives the pathname of the file that your module is called from. Also, worth accepting this answer if it solves your problem.